# How can I control the brightness of an Image?

Tags: java, eclipse, image, bufferedimage, alpha

**I have the following problem:**

I want to create a method to control the brightness of an Image. I think I have to convert it to a BufferedImage before.
And if the Image has an alpha channel and I want to convert it with `TYPE_INT_RGB` the alpha pixels will be black. But it works fine with `TYPE_INT_ARGB`...
It doesn't work if the image doesn't have an alpha channel and I convert it with `TYPE_INT_ARGB`. Then not only the brightness changes, but also the color. When I make the image brighter it becomes more yellow an it becomes blue if I darken it.
Can I convert it in another way or is there a possibility to check if the Image has an alpha channel?

**Here is my code:**

```
public static Image brightnessControl(Image image, float brightness) {

    //First I convert the Image to a BufferedImage
    BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage
            (image.getWidth(null), image.getHeight(null), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Graphics bg = bi.getGraphics();
    bg.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
    bg.dispose();

    //here I brighten/darken the BufferedImage
    RescaleOp rescaleOp = new RescaleOp(brightness, 0, null);
    rescaleOp.filter(bi, bi);

    //I change the BufferedImage back to the Image again!
    image = bi;

    //Last but not least I return the Image...
    return image;
}
```

Comment: Could you try `image = rescaleOp.filter(bi, null);` instead of `rescaleOp.filter(bi, bi);` (see [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/image/RescaleOp.html#filter-java.awt.image.BufferedImage-java.awt.image.BufferedImage-))?

Comment: @howlger If I do that I can't brighten the images with an alpha channel. But it fixes the strange color problem!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look in the code below.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Test {

    public static void main( String[] args ) throws IOException {

        Image img = ImageIO.read( new File( "image.jpeg" ) );

        new JFrame(){
            {
                setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
                setSize( 800, 600 );
                setLocationRelativeTo( null );
                add( new JPanel(){
                    @Override
                    protected void paintComponent( Graphics g ) {

                        super.paintComponent( g );

                        int imgWidth = img.getWidth( null );
                        int imgHeight = img.getHeight( null );
                        int lines = 4;
                        int columns = 6;
                        int count = 1;

                        for ( int i = 0; i < lines; i++ ) {
                            for ( int j = 0; j < columns; j++ ) {
                                g.drawImage( newBrightness( img, 1f/(lines*columns)*count ), imgWidth * j, imgHeight * i, null );
                                count++;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }.setVisible( true );

    }

    public static Image newBrightness( Image source, float brightnessPercentage ) {

        BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage( 
                source.getWidth( null ), 
                source.getHeight( null ), 
                BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB );

        int[] pixel = { 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        float[] hsbvals = { 0, 0, 0 };

        bi.getGraphics().drawImage( source, 0, 0, null );

        // recalculare every pixel, changing the brightness
        for ( int i = 0; i < bi.getHeight(); i++ ) {
            for ( int j = 0; j < bi.getWidth(); j++ ) {

                // get the pixel data
                bi.getRaster().getPixel( j, i, pixel );

                // converts its data to hsb to change brightness
                Color.RGBtoHSB( pixel[0], pixel[1], pixel[2], hsbvals );

                // create a new color with the changed brightness
                Color c = new Color( Color.HSBtoRGB( hsbvals[0], hsbvals[1], hsbvals[2] * brightnessPercentage ) );

                // set the new pixel
                bi.getRaster().setPixel( j, i, new int[]{ c.getRed(), c.getGreen(), c.getBlue(), pixel[3] } );

            }

        }

        return bi;

    }

}
```

It will read a image and create a matrix with new images with new brightnesses. Here is the result for my profile image.

[image]

**EDIT:**

Now it supports alpha too. In the previous code, the alpha component of the new pixel was fixed in 255. I changed to use the alpha component of the original pixel (`pixel[3]`).

[image]

**EDIT 2:**

Each pixel will have a brightness component that varies from 0 to 1. If this component extrapolates the value 1, the pixel will have a "strange" color. You want to have something that seems brighter than the original one, so, you will need to verify if the new brightness value extrapolates 1. The example above will do this. You will have an slider to control what is the maximum percentage that will be calculated to the new pixel brightness component. If this value passes the maximum value (1), the maximum value will be used. I hope that now it finally helps you :D

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSlider;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

public class ChangeImageBrightnessExample2 {

    public static void main( String[] args ) throws IOException {
        new ChangeImageBrightnessExample2().createUI();
    }

    public void createUI() throws IOException {

        Image img = ImageIO.read( new File( "image.jpeg" ) );

        new JFrame(){
            {
                setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
                setSize( 800, 600 );
                setLocationRelativeTo( null );

                CustomPanel panel = new CustomPanel();
                panel.setImage( img );

                JSlider slider = new JSlider( 0, 400, 100 );
                slider.setMinorTickSpacing( 10);
                slider.setMajorTickSpacing( 50 );
                slider.setPaintLabels( true );
                slider.setPaintTicks( true );
                slider.setSnapToTicks( true );
                slider.addChangeListener( new ChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void stateChanged( ChangeEvent evt ) {
                        JSlider s = ((JSlider) evt.getSource());
                        if ( s.getValueIsAdjusting() ) {
                            panel.setMaximumBrightnessPercentage( s.getValue()/100f );
                            panel.repaint();
                        }

                    }
                });

                add( panel, BorderLayout.CENTER );
                add( slider, BorderLayout.SOUTH );

            }
        }.setVisible( true );

    }

    public static Image newBrightness( Image source, float brightnessPercentage ) {

        BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage( 
                source.getWidth( null ), 
                source.getHeight( null ), 
                BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB );

        int[] pixel = { 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        float[] hsbvals = { 0, 0, 0 };

        bi.getGraphics().drawImage( source, 0, 0, null );

        // recalculare every pixel, changing the brightness
        for ( int i = 0; i < bi.getHeight(); i++ ) {
            for ( int j = 0; j < bi.getWidth(); j++ ) {

                // get the pixel data
                bi.getRaster().getPixel( j, i, pixel );

                // converts its data to hsb to change brightness
                Color.RGBtoHSB( pixel[0], pixel[1], pixel[2], hsbvals );

                // calculates the brightness component.
                float newBrightness = hsbvals[2] * brightnessPercentage;
                if ( newBrightness > 1f ) {
                    newBrightness = 1f;
                }

                // create a new color with the new brightness
                Color c = new Color( Color.HSBtoRGB( hsbvals[0], hsbvals[1], newBrightness ) );

                // set the new pixel
                bi.getRaster().setPixel( j, i, new int[]{ c.getRed(), c.getGreen(), c.getBlue(), pixel[3] } );

            }

        }

        return bi;

    }

    private class CustomPanel extends JPanel {

        private float maximumBrightnessPercentage = 1f;
        private Image image;

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent( Graphics g ) {

            super.paintComponent( g );

            int imgWidth = image.getWidth( null );
            int imgHeight = image.getHeight( null );
            int lines = 4;
            int columns = 6;
            int count = 1;

            for ( int i = 0; i < lines; i++ ) {
                for ( int j = 0; j < columns; j++ ) {
                    float newBrightness = maximumBrightnessPercentage/(lines*columns)*count;
                    g.drawImage( newBrightness( image, newBrightness ), imgWidth * j, imgHeight * i, null );
                    g.drawString( String.format( "%.2f%%", newBrightness*100 ), imgWidth * j, imgHeight * i + 10 );
                    count++;
                }
            }

        }

        public void setMaximumBrightnessPercentage( float maximumBrightnessPercentage ) {
            this.maximumBrightnessPercentage = maximumBrightnessPercentage;
        }

        public void setImage( Image image ) {
            this.image = image;
        }

    }

}
```

Take a look in the image below.

[image]

I think now you will understand. If not, I will give up :D

Comment: Thank you! That's what I looked for!

Comment: I tried it out with a PNG-File and for any reason the alpha channel became black... Why?

Comment: @Andy Now it supports alpha.

Comment: Ok! Thank you again!

Comment: But I get strange results when I want to brighten the Image!

Comment: @Andy you need to understand that my code changes the current bright of a pixel based on an percentage (0 to 1) passed to the method. You will need to change how the brightness will be calculated depending of your needs. This will need to be done in this line: `Color c = new Color( Color.HSBtoRGB( hsbvals[0], hsbvals[1], hsbvals[2] * brightnessPercentage ) );`, specifically in the third parameter of `Color.HSBtoRGB` method.

Comment: @Andy the brightness varies from 0 (none) to 1 (maximum). Try to change the hsbvals[2] * brightnessPercentage to only brightnessPercentage. Doing this, the method will change the brightness to 0 to maximum. You will see that the result will be a little bit strange, since now the original pixel brightness will not used as an starting point.

Comment: I tryed it out and the color becomes strange... I changed the line `Color c = new Color( Color.HSBtoRGB( hsbvals[0], hsbvals[1], hsbvals[2] * brightnessPercentage ) );` to `Color c = new Color( Color.HSBtoRGB( hsbvals[0], hsbvals[1], brightnessPercentage ) );`, as you said. But it didn't work... Are you sure it works?

Comment: @Andy they become strange because you are setting the brightness without taking care about the original pixel brightness. You want to make the image brighter than it already is?

Comment: Yes, like in photoshop for example.

Comment: Thank you again! And sorry, I'm not the best in understanding something... :-)

Answer (score 1):

To check of the alpha channel in a `BufferedImage`, use `BufferedImage.getColorModel().hasAlpha();`

```
public static Image brightnessControl(Image image, float brightness) {
    // First I convert the Image to a BufferedImage
    BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(image.getWidth(null), image.getHeight(null), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Graphics bg = bi.getGraphics();

    if (bi.getColorModel().hasAlpha()) { // This will output true because you have just applied TYPE_INT_ARGB!
        System.out.println("Image has got an alpha channel");
    }

    bg.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
    bg.dispose();

    // here I brighten/darken the BufferedImage
    RescaleOp rescaleOp = new RescaleOp(brightness, 0, null);
    rescaleOp.filter(bi, bi);

    // I change the BufferedImage back to the Image again!
    image = bi;

    // Last but not least I return the Image...
    return bi;
}
```

You need to cast the `Image` passed in argument to `BufferedImage` to use the `.getColorModel().hasAlpha()` methods.